# Get the value of standard DDL list in mvc

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor, formcollection

I am using a method that generate my questions and answers i mean every questions appear in view and the answers of this question are put to the DDL as you can see here :

```
public string GenerateHtmlCode()
        {
            string result = string.Empty;
            List<ExecutiveOfficer> executiveOfficers = executiveOfficerRepository.GetAll().ToList();
            List<Indicator> indicators = indicatorRepository.GetAll().ToList();

            foreach (ExecutiveOfficer executiveOfficer in executiveOfficers)
            {
                result += "<div style='width:100%;float:right;'><span>" + executiveOfficer.ExecutiveOfficerText +
                         "</span><span style='float:left'>" +
                         GenerateAnswer(indicatorRepository.FindBy(i => i.ExecutiveOfficerId == executiveOfficer.Id
                                                                  ).ToList(), executiveOfficer.Id) + "</span></div>";
            }


            return result;
        }
```

In my create method in controller i pass the string to viewbag as you can see here :

```
  [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Create(int preliminaryId)
        {
            ViewBag.preliminaryId = preliminaryId;
            ViewBag.pageGenarator = objScoreRepository.GenerateHtmlCode();
           // List<ExecutiveOfficer> executiveOfficer = objScoreRepository.GetAll().ToList();
            //ViewBag.executiveOfficerName = new SelectList(executiveOfficer, "Id", "ExecutiveOfficerText");
            return View("Create");
        }
```

My html code :

```
   </span><span style='float:left'><select id='1' name ='1'><option value='value1'>displaytext</option><option value='value2'>displaytext2</option></select></span>
```

As you can see here i have 1 DDL that has 2 values i need to get the value that is selected by the user i use the `form collection` to get the name of DDl as you can see here :

```
[HttpPost]
        //[Authorize(Roles = "Expert")]
        public ActionResult Create(FormCollection formCollection)
        {
            //objScoreRepository.Add(Score);
            //objScoreRepository.Save();
            foreach (var VARIABLE in formCollection.AllKeys)
            {


            }
            return RedirectToAction("Create", "Score");
        }
```

The `formcollection` just returns one record and the record is `1` the name of `DDL` .But i need to get the value of `DDL`.How can i do that?

My view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutIdeaOtherPage.cshtml";
}

    <h2>Create</h2>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        @Html.Raw(ViewBag.pageGenarator)

        <div class="buttonPossion">
                    <input type="submit"  Class="buttonSave" />
                </div>
    }
```

best regards .

Comment: in my opinion ..just redesign your page architecture you are appending html inside controller which is not a great idea..!!!

Comment: @Kartikeya so do you any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
foreach(string item in form.AllKeys)
{
  var value = Request[item];
}
```

Comment: No, if you html is correct and you select the 1st option in the dropdown, it will return "value1". But why are you not using models and html helpers to render you views and making use of MVC's binding features?

Comment: I have a table that contains questions and a table that contains answers ,there is one to many relation between these two tables ,so i need to show the question and the answers (into ddl),i don't know how can i do that ?!!!

Comment: Your not generating any inputs in your `GenerateHtmlCode` method so nothing else other that the `<select>` you have shown will post back. Your code for creating html in a controller is terrible. You really need to follow a few basic tutorials on using MVC.